# Run java without specifying classpath on the command line

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I've specified the main class and classpath for a java program in the .jar file manifest, but occasionally I want to run a different class from the one specified by the `Main-Class` attribute. Can I get java to launch this class while still pulling the classpath from the manifest, so that I don't have to specify the whole thing on the command line with `-cp`?

Comment: It is possible, because maven's assembly plugin works that way.

Comment: why dont u provide a batch/shell script to run the jar file for u and let that script decide what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the jar file on the command line with -cp; Java will then observe the classpath attribute within the manifest, even though you're not using -jar:

```
java -cp app.jar MyOtherClass
```

Comment: Finally got the chance to confirm... this works! It will append the `Class-Path` attribute to the classpath just the same as using the `-jar` option.